# Class super() unable to inherit "NameError: name 'in_dir' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, super

I'm trying to pass an input directory path from a separate script into the main module "qc".

My first attempt at passing an argument from parent to child in the qc module looks like this:

```
import os

class Data:

    def __init__(self, in_dir):

        # get all inputs
        self.in_dir = in_dir # get input directory

        # get files from input directory
        self.files = os.listdir(self.in_dir) # get file list


class LAS(Data):
    """Takes in log files from parent class Data's file list"""

    def __init__(self):

        # inherit the directory from Data parent
        super().__init__(LAS, in_dir)

        # target only the .las files in the directory
        ext_las = ['.las', '.LAS', '.Las', '.LAs']
        self.lasfiles = [lasfile for lasfile in self.files if any(match in lasfile for match in ext_las)]

    def out_las(self):
        return self.lasfiles
```

When I call the classes from my separate script it looks like this:

```
in_dir = 'C:\\......directory path...'

Data(in_dir=in_dir)

output = LAS().out_las()
```

Which raises the error:

```
  File "C:\......", line 62, in __init__
    super().__init__(LAS, in_dir)

NameError: name 'in_dir' is not defined
```

I can't figure out how to properly call this parent class' inputs.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your `__init__` for your `LAS` class needs to accept the same arguments as its parent class's `__init__` method, otherwise how will you pass those arguments to the parent class? Also, why are you instantiating `Data` and then throwing it away?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python inherit variables from parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561085/python-inherit-variables-from-parent-class)

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to point you in the right direction, but it looks like you're expecting the child class to inherit from an instance of the parent class - but this is not the case.

The following may just work close to what you expect, hope it helps.

```
class LAS(Data):
    """Takes in log files from parent class Data's file list"""

    def __init__(self, in_dir):

        # inherit the directory from Data parent
        super().__init__(in_dir)

        # target only the .las files in the directory
        ext_las = ['.las', '.LAS', '.Las', '.LAs']
        self.lasfiles = [lasfile for lasfile in self.files if any(match in lasfile for match in ext_las)]

    def out_las(self):
        return self.lasfiles


las = LAS(in_dir='C:\\......directory path...')
output = las.out_las()
```